# What term is used for the programs that are educational and entertaining

Tags: terminology

Many programs on internet and TV try to attract customers by teaching through games,so  what is the name of this combination?

Answer (score 5):

I often see the word "**[Infotainment](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infotainment)**" used in in this context, which is a portmanteau of Information and Entertainment.

Another word that comes to me is "**[Gamification](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)**" which can be defined as converting something to a game in order to trigger the desired behaviour. This very site is an example of that.

(Wikipedia links added for additional reference)

Comment: Thanks for the elucidating edit @josh61. I missed out the references 'cos I did not refer to any while writing the answer.

Comment: And that's fine, although corroborating links are always welcome and do improve an answer. What's not necessary is to identify material as "from" somewhere when it's not actually quoted.

Answer (score 4):

The term Edutainment was used for a while, but I don't think it caught on.

Answer (score 0):

Video games that teach you something are often called [Serious Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serious_game) or [Educational Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_game).